# Configrauble product in magento2

Tags: magento2

```
$jsonResult = json_decode($result, true);

        $jsonResult['skus'] = [];
        foreach ($subject->getAllowProducts() as $simpleProduct) {
               $jsonResult['skus'][$simpleProduct->getId()] = $simpleProduct->getSku();
        }
```

I am getting value of text attribute now I want to get the values of those attribute which is drop down

Answer (score 1):

**Magento 2 – Get all attributes of product**

> This small code example returns a list of all product attributes:

```
$product = $this->_productRepository->get("PRODUCTSKU");
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
foreach($attributes as $a)
{
    echo $a->getName()."\n";
}
```

**How to get the configurable attributes of a configurable product?**

```
  /**
  * Retrieve configurable attributes data
  *
  * @param  \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
  * @return \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute[]
  */
public function getConfigurableAttributes($product)
 {
    \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start(
        'CONFIGURABLE:' . __METHOD__,
        ['group' => 'CONFIGURABLE', 'method' => __METHOD__]
    );
    if (!$product->hasData($this->_configurableAttributes)) {
        $configurableAttributes = $this->getConfigurableAttributeCollection($product);
        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process($configurableAttributes);
        $configurableAttributes->orderByPosition()->load();
        $product->setData($this->_configurableAttributes, $configurableAttributes);
    }
    \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('CONFIGURABLE:' . __METHOD__);
    return $product->getData($this->_configurableAttributes);
}
```